# Terms of use page in Angular.JS

Tags: html, angularjs

Problem Question -

I am developing AngularJs App and have Terms of Use and Privacy Policy link, . Where should i store my Terms of Use Page? which is very large.

The options i thought of 
1) Values or Constant ?
2) HTML Page and link it.

Please tell me what is best way to do so. I am asking this because so far I have tried my best to follow best practices with AngularJS and want to continue that.

Comment: How did you want to display them? As a popup, or so that you click on the link, go to that page and view them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's static content you should store it as html in a page. - Option 2)

Comment: The advantage of this is that you don't fetch that content until it is required, which for most users, it probably isn't.